# Recognize Device Position In User's Hand

Tags: android, accelerometer, device-orientation, magnetometer

I need to recognize how a user hold his device. So i tried to use in couple accelerometer and magnetometer in this way:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        switch(event.sensor.getType()) {

            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                mGravity = event.values.clone();
                Log.d("Sensor","ACCEL");
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                Log.d("Sensor","MAGNET");
                mMagnetic = event.values.clone();
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("Sensor","default");

        }
        if(mGravity != null && mMagnetic != null) {
            //float[] temp = new float[9];
            float[] R = new float[9];
            //Load rotation matrix into R
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null,
                    mGravity, mMagnetic);

            //Return the orientation values
            float[] values = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, values);


            //Convert to degrees
            for (int i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
                Double degrees = (values[i] * 180) / Math.PI;
                values[i] = degrees.floatValue();
            }

        }
        if (mValuesOrientation[0]!=0 || mValuesOrientation[1]!=0 || mValuesOrientation[2]!=0 ){
            logOrientation();
        }
    }

    };
```

But i have some problem:

- In the same position i would obtain similar values. But values are so different.

How can i solve?

Comment: It depends on how fine a movement/position you want. The sensors in phones are somewhat noisy so while you might be able to discern big movement, subtle positions are not easily replicated across devices.

Comment: I need three or two values to recognize the user's habit. So after 24h i can see some values or ranges (to consider an error margin) that repeat several times.